# Error after importing a module in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

i've a problem after importing a module in an existing project because after adding the dependencies these errors appears:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :RemoteSupport+.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :RemoteSupport+.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :RemoteSupport+.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

I've already tried to delete the .idea, . gradle files and invalidate Caches/Restart

This is the build.gradle of the app module:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 'Vuzix Corporation:Vuzix M300 SDK:23'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.mtmproject.aures"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 4
            versionName "1.0.3"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
            doNotStrip '*/x86/*.so'
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

        // FIREBASE
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
        implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

        implementation project(path: ':MTMProject')

    }
```

This is the build gradle of the imported module (RemoteSupport):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 26

  sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
  }


  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.appspot.apprtc"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26

    versionCode 15663
    versionName "r15663"

    testApplicationId "org.appspot.apprtc.test"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation files('libs/audio_device_java.jar')
  implementation files('libs/autobanh.jar')
  implementation files('libs/base_java.jar')
  implementation files('libs/libjingle_peerconnection.jar')
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question to contain all information required to answer it. Study [ask] and [mcve] for details.

Comment: Now i've imported the module as "Remote Support", but the errors are the still the same and Android Studio finds the file of the new project but the Classes are 
highlighted in red

Comment: Please post your build.gradle in the question.

Comment: `:MTMProject` might depend on `:RemoteSupport+` (wrong `build.gradle` posted) ...and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` belongs to the bottom of the file.